# Custom Sort Function Python

Tags: python, list, class, sorting

I have a class object which is 5 integer values. I understand that for sorting you override the `__ls__` functions, but I want to be able to sort comparing any of the 5 values, so I would want to have 5 sort keys. Is there any way I can make it easier? I've thought of making a global class switch that keeps track of the correct value but is there an easier way?

Comment: Whats \_\_ls\_\_? Do you mean \_\_eq\_\_, \_\_lt\_\_, \_\_le\_\_, \_\_ne\_\_, \_\_gt\_\_, \_\_ge\_\_ ?

Comment: Can you provide an example data and class? See also [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort by multiple things, it's probably easier not to try to build it into the class, but rather use [the `key` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) for `sorted` when sorting and supply a different function depending on what you want to sort by.